# Inverse of affine linearized polynomial over finite fields

Tags: commutative-algebra, finite-fields, inverse

The following is an affine linearized polynomial in a finite field of order $q^n$:
$$
L(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_ix^{q^i}
$$
In the case that it's a permutation and has an inverse. How can we compute its inverse?

Comment: $x^{q^i} = x$ on $\Bbb{F}_q$. So you probably meant finite field of order $q^n$.

Comment: Thanks @reuns for the observation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This goes back to Dickson and can be done by using the associated matrix as below:

[image]